# Adding Values of a specific label/tag in a spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, spreadsheet, accounting

I am designing a spreadsheet for an accounting framework where I record all the transactions. Say there are 3 categories of transactions: A, B, C.
I want to record the transaction, label my transaction, and get a sum of the labels.

Is there any function, perhaps a dropdown feature, where I could just record the transaction, label it, and the result updates?

Maybe something like in the picture...

[image]

Comment: `SUMIF` and/or a `Pivot Table` come to mind

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest two possible methods,

1. Using Table.
2. Using Dynamic Data Range.

[image]

**How it works:**

*Method 1:*

- Insert Table.
- Make necessary changes in Table design.
- Write `SUMIF` formula in `D30:D32`.

`=SUMIF(Table1[Label],"A",Table1[Value])`.

**N.B.** *Fill down the formula, where criteria `A` is editable.*

---

*Method 2:*

- From **F**ormula TAB, click **N**ame Manager, **N**ew.

[image]

- Enter Name & Formula.
- Finish with **O**k, & repeat for other Dynamic Data Range also.

---

- Formula to create Dynamic Data Range.

`=OFFSET(Sheet2!$H$20,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!$H:$H),1)`

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!$I$20,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!$I:$I),1)
```

- `SUMIF` formula in cell `L20`.

`=SUMIF(MYLabel,"A",MYData)`.

---

**N.B.**

- *As soon you enter new Label & corresponding Values in **T**able and in  **C**olumn `H` & `I`, then Excel automatically adjust new Values in `SUMIF`
  formula.*
- *Adjust Named Range & Cell references as needed.*